# NullPointerException in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on fragments in my current application.

I am displaying 3 different tabs each of which having a fragment. I am getting a null pointer exception while accessing the view. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView text;

public DetailsFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.ride_details_fragment,
            null);
    text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_ride_name);

            text.setText("Current Tab is: ");

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
//

}
```

Exception is in line text.setText. Here is the exception logs:

```
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bb/com.android.ui.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at com.android.ride.ui.DetailsFragment.onCreateView(DetailsFragment.java:43)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5057)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2054)
03-24 19:15:40.138: E/AndroidRuntime(13611):    ... 11 more
```

Can somebody help me in finding the root cause of the exception? It would be a great to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to get another inflater instead of provided one?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ride_details_fragment,
                container, false);
    text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_ride_name);
    text.setText("Current Tab is: ");

    return v;
}
```

And please make sure you have id = `txt_ride_name` (case-sensitive) inside `ride_details_fragment.xml`

Comment: Now, I am using the provided inflater. Everything is in place. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception is in line text.setText.

Your `ride_details_fragment.xml` does not have a `TextView` with id `txt_ride_name`.

Either you inflated the wrong layout or your layout does not have the view with the id specified.

Comment: I inflated correct layout. Also I am having the textview with same id. I have cross checked. Thanks

Comment: @Nemat that cannot be. You are missing something. NPE is because `text` is null and its not initialized properly. Again i stress the point that you infalte wrong layout or you referenced wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

check that your  `ride_details_fragment` contains textView with id `txt_ride_name` or not. this would be cause of this exception.

Comment: thanks.... But I dont know what went wrong. I created another layout, copy-pasted the last one in this and it works fine. :)